# Go: Connect to SMTP server and send multiple emails in one connection?

Tags: email, go, smtp, smtp-auth

I'm writing a package which I intend to make one initial connection to the local SMTP server and then it waits on a channel which will be populated with emails to send when they are needed to be sent.

Looking at net/http it appears to be expecting that the SMTP server should be dialed into and authenticated each time an email is to be sent. Surely I can dial and authenticate once, keep the connection open and just add new emails as they come?

Looking at the source for `smtp.SendMail`, I don't see how this can be done, as there does not appear to be a way to recycle the `*Client`:
http://golang.org/src/net/smtp/smtp.go?s=7610:7688#L263

There is a `Reset` function for `*Client`, but the description for that is:

```
 Reset sends the RSET command to the server, aborting the current mail transaction.
```

I don't want to abort the current mail transaction, I want to have multiple mail transactions.

How can I keep the connection to the SMTP server open and send multiple emails on that one connection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct that `smtp.SendMail` does not provide a way to reuse the connection.

If you want that fine grained control, you should use a persistent client connection. This will require knowing a bit more about the smtp commands and protocol.

1. Use `smtp.Dial` to open a connection and create a client object.
2. Use `client.Hello`, `client.Auth`, and `client.StartTLS` as appropriate.
3. Use `Rcpt`, `Mail`, `Data` as approprate to send messages.
4. `client.Quit()` and close connection when you are all done.

Comment: Thanks... at what point does the connection reset for sending another email? Do I use `client.Quit()` at the end of each message or at the end of sending all messages?

Comment: quit means "I am done and ready to disconnect." Only send it at the end of all messages.

Comment: No need for step one (opening a `net.Conn` yourself). You can just use `smtp.Dial`. Basically, just do almost exactly what `smtp.SendMail` does except that before calling `Quit` loop back and do more `Mail`, `Rcpt`, and `Data` calls.

Comment: In this case then, I will never run Quit() or Close() since the Go webapp remains dialed into the SMTP server at all times. Will the connection automatically terminate when the Go app exits?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I put the Quit and Close as deferred in the goroutine that waits on the channels anyway. So when the goroutine is terminated then it will close the connection.

Comment: @DaveC I think you are not correct. In case something goes wrong within any call, not calling `Quit` and `Dial` again will leave you with errors like on every message after the faulty one (in case of an error happening after first `Mail` call, in `Rcpt` or `Data`, every next message will fail on `Mail` call with error  `503 Only one sender per message, please` for example).

Answer (score 3):

Gomail v2 now supports sending multiple emails in one connection. The [Daemon example](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#example-package--Daemon) from the documentation seems to match your use case:

```
ch := make(chan *gomail.Message)

go func() {
    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer("smtp.example.com", 587, "user", "123456")

    var s gomail.SendCloser
    var err error
    open := false
    for {
        select {
        case m, ok := <-ch:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            if !open {
                if s, err = d.Dial(); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                open = true
            }
            if err := gomail.Send(s, m); err != nil {
                log.Print(err)
            }
        // Close the connection to the SMTP server if no email was sent in
        // the last 30 seconds.
        case <-time.After(30 * time.Second):
            if open {
                if err := s.Close(); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                open = false
            }
        }
    }
}()

// Use the channel in your program to send emails.

// Close the channel to stop the mail daemon.
close(ch)
```